# Return custom object to GraphQL resolver

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express, graphql

I need to provide custom custom Object as ouput for GraphQL resolver.

This is for Node-Express backend server with GraphQL setup. I tried sequelized, but I'm testing a new approach, where i need to pass an object as output to graphQL.

```
const RootQueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Query",
  fields: {
  Sample: {
      type: SampleType,
      args: {
        sampleID: { type: GraphQLID }
      },
      resolve: async (parent, args) => {
        try {
          const result = await sql.connect(config).then(pool =>
            pool
              .request()
              .input("sampleID", sql.Int, args.sampleID)
              .query(
                "SELECT * FROM samples WHERE sampleID = @sampleID"
              )
          );
          const ASB = await result.recordsets[0];
          console.log(ASB);
          sql.close();
          return ASB;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          sql.close();
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

the result of the query output is

```
[
  {
     sampleID: 1,
     sampleText: 'sample1'
  },
  {
     sampleID: 2,
     sampleText: 'sample2'
  }
]
```

When i return plain object i.e. ASB[0]

```
{
     sampleID: 1,
     sampleText: 'sample1'
}
```

I am getting output in GraphQL but when the entire ASB object is returned, I'm not able to get ouput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're declaring the type as single item `SampleType` but returning the array of `SampleType`

you can fix it be changing `SampleType` to `new GraphQLList(SampleType)`

```js
const RootQueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Query",
  fields: {
  Sample: {
      type: new GraphQLList(SampleType), // THIS LINE !!!
      args: {
        sampleID: { type: GraphQLID }
      },
      resolve: async (parent, args) => {
        try {
          const result = await sql.connect(config).then(pool =>
            pool
              .request()
              .input("sampleID", sql.Int, args.sampleID)
              .query(
                "SELECT * FROM samples WHERE sampleID = @sampleID"
              )
          );
          const ASB = await result.recordsets[0];
          console.log(ASB);
          sql.close();
          return ASB;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          sql.close();
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```